How to filter password user input char-wise for special characters, suppressing ESC sequences in Bash?
I'm trying to find a solution which can filter user input for a password char-wise via read command (not by read -e, which prevents directly responding to key strokes), filtering and handling special characters in real-time. As first char, space or any special chars shouldn't be allowed. How to achieve that, yet avoiding non-printable ESC-sequences (everything which moves the cursor, apart from backspace), which potentially would pollute the password input?
# Set of allowed chars
allowedDefaultChars='[a-zA-Z0-9]'
allowedSpecialChars='[-_ \(\)/~?!§,.\#+]'
pw=
while true; do
    read -rsn 1
    if [[ $REPLY ]]; then
        ...
        pw+="$REPLY"
    fi
done
echo "$pw"


Through further investigation and experimentation, I've come to the following solution:
#! /bin/bash

# Validated password entry with filtered ESC sequences / disabled ESC and a set of allowed special chars / disallows special chars or space as 1st char
validate_password() {

    local pw
    local escKey=$'\x1B'
    local backspaceKey=$'\x7f'
    local allowedDefaultChars='[a-zA-Z0-9]'
    local allowedSpecialChars='[-_ \(\)/~?!§,.\#+]'
    echo -e "\n*** Password validation ***\nAllowed special charset, unless 1st char is >> $allowedSpecialChars <<\n\nEnter password:" >/dev/tty
    local isFirstChar="1"
    while true; do
        read -rsn 1
        # Stop on ENTER
        if [[ ${#REPLY} -eq 0 ]]; then
            break
        fi
        # Filter ESC sequences / block ESC key
        if [[ $REPLY == $escKey ]]; then
            while true; do
                read -rsn1 -t 0.001
                if [[ ${#REPLY} -eq 0 ]]; then
                    break
                fi
            done
            continue
        fi
        # Block 1st char special char or space
        if [[ $isFirstChar ]]; then
            if [[ $REPLY != $allowedDefaultChars ]]; then
                echo -e "First char must not be a special char or space!\e[1A" >/dev/tty
                continue
            fi
            # Clear and stay in message line
            echo -e "\e[K\e[1A" >/dev/tty
            unset -v isFirstChar
        fi
        # Filter out disallowed chars for input
        if [[ $REPLY == $allowedDefaultChars || $REPLY == $allowedSpecialChars ]]; then 
            pw+="$REPLY" 
            printf '%s' '*' >/dev/tty
        # Backspace - delete last entered password char and a '*' from dispay
        elif [[ $REPLY == $backspaceKey ]]; then
            pw="${pw:0:-1}" 
            printf '%s' $'\e[1D\e[0K' >/dev/tty
        fi
    done
    
    echo "$pw"
    unset pw
    echo -e >/dev/tty
}

echo -e "PW IS: $(validate_password)"

The function blocks any input of special chars or space as 1st char, showing a warning message. Upon entering the 1st valid char, all further chars from either valid set of allowedDefaultChars or allowedSpecialChars, are added to the local pw var, printing the next * on screen.
All visual output is redirected to >/dev/tty, so as not to pollute the password, if capturing the function call into a var.
If backspace is pressed, the nexte previously stored char, along with the its * representation on screen, is removed again.
All directly from keyboard accessible keys generating ESC-sequences / non-printable chars, should be successfully suppressed and filtered (ESC, F1-F12, arrow keys, home, end, pgup, pgdn, ...), even on upon excessive, rapid multiple keypressing, without 'leaked' key sequences.
ENTER finishes the input.
I've also tested copy'n'paste input from KeepassXC, which seemed to work fine (unless the pasted password contains forbidden chars).
